# Set System Properties or Environment Variables Before Property Placeholder with SpringJunit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, properties, junit

I have a main app-context.xml that defines a property placeholder with two locations: default properties file and an optional override file:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:config.properties,${configOverride}"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

The optional override location allows specifying another properties file (e.g. "-DconfigOverride=file:/home/app/config.properties") with only the properties that should be overridden.

For my unit tests, I'm using a test context that imports app-context.xml:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-context.xml"})
public class UserServiceTest {
    ...
}
```

How can I set system properties or environment variables within the application before the application context is loaded? I would like to achieve the same effect as setting "-DconfigOverride=classpath:testConfig.properties" across all test classes without having to specify a command line arg, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thinking of ,

1. Extending `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and setting the system property
   `configOverride` in its constructor/initialization block
2. Then passing `ExtendedSpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to `@RunWith`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion +1 - I thought the same thing but wanted to check if there was anything I can do in the application context before I go and modify all the test classes. I override a few beans in the test context, but unfortunately, since multiple property placeholders are allowed, I can't override the property placeholder.

Answer (score 16):

One other alternative is setting the environment property in a @BeforeClass annotated method, which will be invoked before the Context Configuration happens.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setSystemProps() {
    System.setProperty("configOverride", "yourVal");
}
```

Comment: And maybe a `System.clearProperty("configOverride")` in an `@AfterClass`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This definitely would work too. I was hoping to keep the only hard-coded string in the test class as the spring context path but sometimes it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up doing - I didn't have to change any unit test classes. Unfortunately, I didn't set the "configOverride" property (see AhamedMustafaM's answer for one way to do that) and instead went with overriding the original property placeholder definition (I tried again after my initial failed attempts and got it to work).

I added the following line to my testContext.xml:

```xml
<!-- import the main app context -->
<import resource="classpath:appContext.xml" />

<!-- this is the line i added -->
<context:property-placeholder order="-999"
        location="classpath:testConfig.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Note the order="-999" attribute, which is used to ensure priority over the original property-placeholder definition(s). Also I set "ignore-unresolvable" to "true" to delegate any unresolvable properties to the original placeholder configurer.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was similar but I wanted to set the `spring.profiles.active` environment variable and it turned out that I just needed to throw [`@ActiveProfiles()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) with the values I wanted on to the test itself.